# how to use Maven with jazz RTC?

Tags: maven-2, jazz

I am using maven with subversion and clearcase for more than 4 years.
My new project is in Jazz RTC with Ant as a build tool.
I want to move from Ant to Maven2 or Maven3.
I am new to Jazz RTC. Please guide me on how to use Maven with Jazz RTC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This article is a great introduction: "[When Maven meets Rational Team Concert](http://phkrief.wordpress.com/2010/09/24/when-maven-meets-rational-team-concert/)"

[image]

> once the user has chosen to create a Build Definition using the Maven Build template, he needs to specify:
>
> 1. in which folder is stored the pom.xml (Project location) and
> 2. which Maven goals to reach during the build. That’s it!

- The [wiki page on Maven build](http://jazz.net/wiki/bin/view/Main/MavenBuild) is quite complete.
- The FAQ on [How do I use the Jazz SCM Provider for Maven?](https://jazz.net/wiki/bin/view/Main/UsingMavenScmPlugin) refers to the [Maven SCM Plugin](https://jazz.net/wiki/bin/view/Main/MavenScmPluginDev).